# v-for anidado para agregar multiples inputs en cada fila y columna especifica de una tabla

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Como se podria agregar multiples inputs en cada fila de una columna especifica, la idea es, tengo un v-for que me genera la tabla y en cada fila tengo un boton agregar "peridodo" que me agregaria multiples inputs en una columna en la respectiva fila de dicha columna,les agrego una imagen para que se comprenda mejor lo que quiero hacer:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

les agrego el código que hice:

```
<div id="app" class="content">
<div class="row">
    <div class="span8 offset2">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <h1>CARGA DE NOVEDADES</h1>
                <h3>Unidad Organizativa: {{data.usuario.organismoPadre}}</h3>
                <h3>Periodo: Agosto - Septiembre 2018</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span12">
                    <h2>Reemplazos Autorizados</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span12">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                        <thead>
                        <td>orden</td>
                        <td>Formulario</td>
                        <td>Motivo</td>
                        <td>Nivel</td>
                        <td>Reemplazante</td>
                        <td>Reemplazado</td>
                        <td>Autorizado Desde</td>
                        <td>Hasta</td>
                        <td>Trabajo Periodo Completo</td>
                        <td>No trabajo</td>
                        <td>Desde</td>
                        <td>Hasta</td>
                        <td>Agregar Periodo</td>
                        <td>Guardar</td>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr v-if="data.novedades!=null" v-for="(novedad,key) in data.novedades">
                            <td>{{ key+1  }}</td>
                            <td>{{novedad.tipo_formulario}}</td>
                            <td>{{novedad.motivo}}</td>
                            <td>{{novedad.nivel}}</td>
                            <td v-html="novedad.reemplazante"></td>
                            <td v-html="novedad.reemplazado"></td>
                            <td>{{novedad.fdesde}}</td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="periodo_completo"></td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="no_trabajo"></td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="" v-for="(periodo,index) in novedad.periodos">
                                        <div class="fechas">
                                        <input type="date" class="form-control" v-model="novedad.periodos.fdesde">
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div></td>
                            <input type="date" name="">

                            <td>
                                <button class="btn btn-mini btn-danger">Eliminar</button>
                            </td>
                            <td><button class="btn btn-mini btn-success" @click="addPeriodo(key)">Agregar Periodo</button></td>
                            <td><a class="btn btn-mini btn-danger" href="#">Guardar</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
            data: {
                    novedades:[
                        {
                            periodos: [
                            {
                                fdesde: '',
                            }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    usuario: {
                                organismoPadre: null
                    },
            },

    },
    methods: {
        addPeriodo (key) {
            // var elem = document.createElement('div');
            this.data.novedades[key].periodos  = [];
            this.data.novedades[key].periodos.push({
                fdesde: '',
            });
            console.log(this.data.novedades[key].periodos);
            console.log(key);
        },
        // removeElement: function(index) {
        //     this.rows.splice(index, 1);
        // },
    },
    created() {
        axios.get('http://localhost/desarrollo/php/yii/rrhh/index.php?r=formulario2/F2NovedadesData').then(response => this.data = response.data);
    }

});
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podrias subir una especie de imagen de que queres que pase y que esta pasando ahora? no termino de comprender tu problema.

Comment: muchas gracias @gbianchi ya he agregado una imagen prototipo de lo que intento hacer.

Comment: Solo como control, te esta agregando las filas que queres, pero no las esta mostrando no? es como que no reacciona a los cambios?

Comment: claro, no esta reaccionando a los cambios, pero aparte de eso en el console.log que tengo ahi solo me muestra que agrega un dato al vector, no agrega mas que eso.

Comment: Bueno lo de que agregue un solo dato es correcto porque es lo que estas haciendo. Podes hacer un [mcve] para que lo miremos? definitivamente no esta reaccionando a los cambios en vector hijo. Supongo que si probas agregar una fila al padre lo hace.

Comment: exacto, comence aprendiendo con un solo vector, y ahi funcionaba, cuando implemente para hacerlo dentro y utilizando un **key** como indice me comenzo a dar este fallo, me pongo a ver de hacer el ejemplo minimo y lo agrego.

Comment: el key ese se genera en el primer v-for seria el indice del array en cada fila de la tabla

Comment: De este código me guié una parte:

https://jsfiddle.net/kndeh3r4/2

Comment: el index en el segundo parametro me permite eliminar en otro metodo que ahi todavia no esta puesto para identificar, fijate que seria un array dentro de otro entonces al momento de querer eliminar un input necesito ese segundo indice.

Comment: Si perfecto. me mareo el codigo. En teoria esta todo bien. Fijate [aca](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html) si no estas cayendo en alguno de los problemas que hacen que no sea reactiva la lista.